# Firebase Cloud Functions and PWA Service Worker

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a JavaScript web app using Firebase. I also prepare much of the content through cloud functions. My logic was to make the page load faster because the pieces can show up asynchronously. Now, I think it would be good to transition to a PWA with a service worker for offline usage. I'm using cloud functions as https callable functions.

For example:

```
    var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var functions = app.functions();

    var dataReq = functions.httpsCallable('getData');
    dataReq().then(function(res) {
            // Consume the result.
    }).catch(function(err) {
            // Do something.
    });
```

Is there a way to, or does Firebase automatically, cache the cloud functions response locally?